# Resume Execution from where a function left  -Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I have an app coded in Applescript where a  dialog pops up with three buttons: {Help, Add, Subtract} .
When user taps the Help button, a dialog should popup displaying information about the app.This dialog will have a {Cancel,Continue} button. When user taps the Continue button, he should be returned to the previous dialog( The dialog with three buttons: {Help, Add, Subtract}). But I cant get it to work. Here is my code:

```
set question to display dialog "I want to" buttons {"Help", "Add", "Subtract"} default button 2

set response to button returned of question

if response is equal to "Help" then

  Help()

 end if

ere is my Help Function

 on Help()

   display dialog "blah blah" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"}

return

 end Help
```

How do I resume execution with the dialog with three button?

Answer (score 0):

You can “go back and do it again” with a [`repeat` loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-127362):

```
repeat
    ⋮
    set response to …
    if response is equal to "Help" then
        Help()
    else
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat
```

Or with `repeat while`:

```
set response to "Help" -- just the inital condition
repeat while response is equal to "Help"
    ⋮
    set response to …
    if response is equal to "Help" then
        Help()
    else
end repeat
```

Comment: I get an error:                                                    "Finder got an error: Cant continue Help"  I forgot to add that this code is enclosed inside 'tell application "Finder"'

Comment: Use `my` to call to your own handlers from inside an application `tell` block: `my Help()`.